# problems with different importing styles in Python 2.7.2

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to mimic some of the C programs in the Kernighan and  Ritchie C programming book and have run into problems with getchar(). I have got the initial program working but when I move getchar() to its own file stdio.py it only works with calls like **stdio.getchar()** after declaring *import stdio*, not with calls that have the  declaration  type of : *from stdio import ** using a call in the form of **getchar().

**My working code in FileCopy.py**

```
import stdio
import StringIO

def FileCopy():
    c = stdio.getchar()
    while (c!=stdio.EOF):
        stdio.putchar(c)
        c = stdio.getchar()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    SRC = raw_input(">>")
    print "Echoe: ",
    stdio.FP = StringIO.StringIO(SRC)
    FileCopy()
```

**code for my stdio.py**

```
"""
 Python implementation of getchar
"""

EOF =""

# python specific
import StringIO

FP = None
def getchar():
    if FP:
        return FP.read(1)

def ungetc(c=''):
    if FP:
        FP.seek(-1, os.SEEK_CUR)

def putchar(c):
    print c,
```

OK so far so good. However the calls to stdio.getchar() look ugly so I used the *form stdio import ** and removed them.The main idea was to remove all prefixes for readability.No changes were made to stdio.py.

```
"""
File Copy
Kernighan Ritchie page 16
stdio has been created in Python file stdio.py
and defines standard output functions putchar,getchar and EOF
"""

from stdio import *
import StringIO

def FileCopy():
    c = getchar()
    while (c!=EOF):
        putchar(c)
        c = getchar()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    SRC = raw_input(">>")
    print "Echoe: ",
    FP = StringIO.StringIO(SRC)
    FileCopy()
```

The output;

An infinite call to getchar() as the FP variable always returns NONE. I therefore get infinate NONE in the output shell.

Question.
Why doess the first example initialise the FP variable in stdio.py and the second example does not? 
Is there a simple fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globals in Python are global to a module, not across all modules.  You have different FPs in different scopes.

You've already come up with a simple fix.  Import the module such that you explicitly reference the module's variable name.

This is an example of why it's not a good practice to "import *"

From the official Python 2.75 FAQ: [How do I share global variables across modules?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules)

What you suggest is "*ugly*", others might say is explicit and precise.  I expect that the other alternatives I could think of would be just as ugly. Do the *ugly*.

Comment: It is a fair point but EOF is a global in stdio.h in C across other modules. However, it could all be avoided with a class. I just really like Kernighnan's programming style and wanted to use it! Thanks for the reference.